# How to cycle through a list of images without the images taking time to load in dart?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, caching

In my app I have an **InkWell** on an image that I want to turn into a different image when you click on it. I have set up a list where the onTap simply cycles through the list onto the next image.
The problem is, when you click it, it takes about half a second for the next image to load.
I would like to be able to show the images instantaneously when clicking it.

```
int index = 0;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List images = [
      Image.asset('assets/image0.jpg'),
      Image.asset('assets/image1.jpg'),
      Image.asset('assets/image2.jpg'),
      Image.asset('assets/image3.jpg'),
    ];
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      },
      child: images[index],
    );
  }
```

This is my current code

Answer (score 3):

> it takes about half a second for the next image to load

This is probably because your `List` of `images` is *within* your `build` method, so every `setState` it rebuilds.

Move your List *outside* of the `build` method:

```dart
 int index = 0;
  List images = [
    Image.asset('assets/image0.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/image1.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/image2.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/image3.jpg'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      },
      child: images[index],
    );
  }
```